# Selecting a specific row from an rpy2 DataFrame

Tags: rpy2

My data frame is survey data that I have got from a .csv file. One of the columns is age and I am looking to remove all respondents under 18 years of age. I'll then need to isolate age groups (18-24, 25-35, etc) into their own dataframes that I can do frequency distributions for.

[The R code is simple enough](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm):

```
x.sub <- subset(x.df, y > 2)
```

But I can't figure out how to use the r() function to get my dataframe variable from python into an R statement. It feels as though there ought to be a .subset() function in the rpy2 DataFrame class. But if it exists, I can't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using rpy2 2.2.0-dev (should be the same with 2.1.x)

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
dataf = DataFrame.from_csvfile("my/file.csv")

dataf_subset = dataf.rx(dataf.rx2("age").ro >= 18, True)
```

That one exact example is not in the documentation (and may be should be there), but it's constituting elements are:[extracting elements](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html#extracting-elements) and [R operators on vectors](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html#operators)

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that. Appreciated.